# Tool for cleaning up CSS?

Tags: css, tidy

Before publishing a site I have bloat of unused CSS styles. Is there any good tool to detect unused CSS classes, divs?

> **Related Questions:**
>
> - [Tool to identify unused css definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions)
> - [Are there any utilites that will help me refactor CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114272/are-there-any-utilites-that-will-help-me-refactor-css)

Comment: Please check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions). and related questions in the RHS.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try CSS Tidy:

http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/

It is simple yet effective.

Comment: this is not an appropriate answer for this question, as css tidy does not identify unused css rules

Comment: @alegscogs: Hm, you are indeed correct..don't know how I missed it, or why was it accepted then.. >_>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple web based css optimizer, very useful:
http://www.cleancss.com/

Comment: This doesn't remove unused classes either.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ProCSSor](http://procssor.com)

Comment: This doesn't remove unused classes either.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have firebug (for Firefox, if you don't know), and then install the pagespeed plugin for firebug, developed by Google:

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/

It will give you a 'pageSpeed' tab in firebug.  Open it and, with 'performance' selected, click 'analyze performance'.  Along with lots of other useful suggestions, you will get a list item labelled "Remove Unused Css".  Click to expand it and see a breakdown by resource of unused css rules appearing on the present page, along with the memory size that you will save by removing the unused rules.

Comment: how do you accomplish same in chrome?

Comment: the pagespeed plugin is developed by google and available for chrome as well as firefox.