# Programmatically separate stylesheet into sub-stylesheets?

Tags: css

Say you have a massive stylesheet with a full site worth of selectors, each loaded with  properties in it (positioning, sizing, fonts, colors, etc... all together) and you want to separate them into different, appropriate files (e.g. fonts.css, colors.css, layout.css, etc..)..

Are there any known (automated) methods for completing such a task?

Example:

```
#myid {
display:block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #f00;
background-color:#f00;
font-size:.75em;
color:#000;
}
```

Would be converted to the following 3 files:

layout.css:

```
#myid {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

color.css:

```
#myid {
    border:1px solid #f00;
    background-color:#f00;
    color:#000;
}
```

fonts.css:

```
#myid {
    font-size:.75em;
}
```

My example probably doesn't utilize the best conventions for doing this, but a way to automate the separation of the properties into different files would be very convenient in framework creation, I imagine.

Comment: See the answered question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114272/are-there-any-utilites-that-will-help-me-refactor-css

Comment: I appreciate the link, but nothing on that page actually "separates" stylesheets.

Comment: From the looks of things, I'm gonna have to write something to do this myself.

Comment: Aren't you doing this the wrong way round? Shouldn't you be serving up one consolidated stylesheet instead of separate ones?

Comment: If you explained why you want to separate the aggregate stylesheet into a bunch of smaller files, we might be able to offer alternatives to your underlying problem.  As it stands now, it doesn't make much sense to do what your asking.

Comment: I'll be using drupal's method of compiling all of the stylesheets into one and caching this new, compressed sheet. So, the separation of sheets is not problematic (it actually is necessary to deal with drupal's size, I think)

Comment: To each his/her own, but personally I found that three separate sheets was annoying to maintain. I just open my main stylesheet and search for a selector after identifying something in Firebug. Also: consider that `border` affects both color and layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cssutils

PATH_TO_CSS_FILE = 'old_huge_css_file.css'

LAYOUT = ('display', 'width', 'height', 'margin', 'padding',
          'position', 'top', 'left', 'bottom', 'right')
COLOR = ('color', 'background', 'border', 'background-color')
FONTS = ('font', 'font-size')

def strip_styles(infile_path, outfile_path, properties_to_keep):
    stylesheet = cssutils.parseFile(infile_path)

    for rule in stylesheet:
        if not rule.type == rule.STYLE_RULE:
            continue

        [ rule.style.removeProperty(p) for p in rule.style.keys() 
            if not p in properties_to_keep ]

    f = open(outfile_path, 'w')
    f.write(stylesheet.cssText)
    f.close()

segments = (
    ('layout.css', LAYOUT),
    ('color.css', COLOR),
    ('fonts.css', FONTS),
)

for segment in segments:
    strip_styles(PATH_TO_CSS_FILE, *segment)
```

You'll need [CssUtils](http://code.google.com/p/cssutils/)

And obviously I havn't filled in the tuples at the beginning with every possible css property. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader

**note**: It will leave all the comments in the stylesheet even though many of them will not pertain to the separated styles.

Also, all styles not enumerated in the `LAYOUT`, `COLOR`, and `FONTS` variables at the top will be filtered out.

You can easily modify the `strip_styles` function to filter out the styles in those three variables to make a 4th stylesheet that contains all the misc. properties if you like

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Copy your big stylesheet to the 3 files.
2. Open each one and remove the styles you don't need.

For step 2, you can save a lot of time by using search/replace in an editor like Notepad++. For example in layout.css, you could do a regex search for `^.*background:.+$` and replace with nothing. (Then at the end remove all blank lines.)

In theory you should be able to reduce this to only a couple of regexes per file, but Notepad++ doesn't seem to like the pipe character, or parentheses for that matter. `^.*background(-color|-image)?:.+$` ought to work, but it doesn't.

This isn't programmatic, but TBH by the time you'd written your own code to do what you're asking you could have typed the stylesheets out from scratch.

Answer (score 7):

Roll your own.  Valid CSS should not be terribly difficult to parse.

- Split the entire file by `}`
- In each of those, what comes before the `{` is the selector
- Split what comes after `{` by `;` to get each individual rule for each selector
- Evaluate each rule and build your files accordingly

Semi-pseudo VB.NET code...

```
 Dim CssFile as String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("MyFile.css")
 Dim CssRules as String() = CssFile.Split("}")

 For Each Rule as String in CssRules
     Dim Selector as String = Rule.Substring(0, Rule.IndexOf("{")).Trim();
     Dim Styles as String() = Rule.Substring(Rule.IndexOf("{") + 1).Trim().Split(";");

     For Each Style as String in Styles
         If Style.StartsWith("font") Then 
              ' Build your files... yada, yada, yada
         End If
     Next
 Next
```

Comment: Interesting approach you've come up with here! Thank you for your feedback. I'll have to try converting your methods to a language I can hack in =]

Answer (score 7):

Do you have a command line grep?  Do you care about comments in the output?  Can you do a first pass to clean up the formatting?  For example in your editor of choice ensure that `{`,`}`, and `;` are followed by a new-line.  Then these might get you close:

```
grep -i '[{]\|[}]\|background\|border\|color' source.css > color.css
grep -i '[{]\|[}]\|font\|letter\|line-height' source.css > font.css
grep -v 'background\|border\|color\|font\|letter\|line-height' source.css > layout.css
```

You'll have to make adjustments if you don't want any of the following tags in the layout.css: `outline-*`, `text-*`, `white-space`, `word-spacing`.  That is if your css uses them.  I'd also take a quick look to see what tags you are actually using.  For example,

```
grep -v '[{]\|[}]' test2.css | sed -e 's/:.*$//g' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 4):

The easy part is going to be parsing CSS. The hard part is classifying the different CSS directives and anticipating short-hand CSS selectors.

CSSTidy might be the ticket with some modifications. Not only will it parse CSS but it will also consolidate CSS properties whenever possible:

http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/download.php

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any methods that will separate out your css automatically, but the Blueprint CSS framework has this already broken out for you & in times past I've just plugged in my styles where needed & it took care of all the misc browser differences.

www.blueprintcss.org

Comment: I suppose cutting and pasting into pre-made framework files is the best available method.. still seems like there would be an incredible amount of work pasting into each, then removing the inappropriate selectors for that appropriate file (especially if the css file you're splitting up is like 1000+ lines).

I think it's safe to say that I have a new programming project on my hands.

Comment: Usually you can over-ride the each stylesheet just by how you place the next one. It's been a while since I've had to rely on this method, but say you list the Blueprint CSS out in your header, and then your stylesheet, any declarations found in both css files will be overridden by the last one declared (or you could say, by the css file closest to your ending </header> tag). You may want to test that out tho, like I said, it had been a while.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a useful tool, I thought it might already exist, but I couldn't find anything.

I think you probably would need to create it. To do so you can probably leverage one of the many existing CSS parser libraries or programs that are out there.

A quick search reveals multiple ones in .NET, Java, Ruby, etc. There's even questions about this on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Really easy to roll your own script. [Here](http://code.dunae.ca/css_parser/) is a library for css in ruby, im sure you can find one with whatever platform you happen to use

Answer (score 0):

```
* Split the entire file by }
* In each of those, what comes before the { is the selector
* Split what comes after { by ; to get each individual rule for each selector
* Evaluate each rule and build your files accordingly
```

Answer (score -1):

I've done two big projects with multiple styles in the past months.

In one case there were different colors and styles per page. In the other case some colors and images were different for target groups.

I created a stylesheet **main.css** which contained the positioning, default fonts, spacing and everything else you'd expect in a stylesheet. Then for each target group I created an extra stylesheet containing the specific coloring, fonts and (background) images.

In your case, builing a framework, I would at least suggest the following components:

- ***Reset***
- ***Main***
- ***Typography***

One thing to keep in mind is the number of HTTP requests you're making by calling other stylesheets. If possible use as little stylesheets as possible.

Answer (score -2):

Have you thought about using a program that takes care of the CSS for you, instead of manually going through and editing it all yourself? I've recently started using [stylizer](http://www.skybound.ca/) and I'm impressed with all the functions it has available (even in the free version). Although it won't split the CSS files like you want as far as I can tell.